# How do I call internal function in bash if I have defined with the same name?

Tags: bash

I want to overload the functionality of `cd` in bash so that I can do the following checks:

if the directory is not in DIRSTACK -> `pushd dir`

else `cd dir` (or `cd ~#`)

However now I get a recursive loop when trying to `cd`

The reason for this is that I am trying to work around the fact that bash does not support `set dunique`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the builtin called "builtin":

```
cd () {
    builtin cd "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See also [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/pushd_and_popd.shtml) for various attempts to workaround this.